# UIView stretch view to point

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I have a UIImage with an anchorpoint of:

`self.myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)`

which is basically the anchor is the left side of the view.

Now I want to make `CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)` stretch towards a point in a view. Is this possible? So: illustrated it would be

[image]

Imagine that it also can rotates for example 45 degree. It should always point to the little speaker. So thats why I don't want to bother with calculating angles and stuff. I just want `1.0, 0.5` to point o the speaker. How do I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't that work with `CGAffineTransformation` and then scale into the `x` direction only? You could calculate the scale factor from the current `maxX`.

Comment: Which constructor would you use for `CGAffineTransformation` @LinusGeffarth? Because `scaleX, y` and `translationX, y` aren't doing their jobs.